# translating curl request to php

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to use and API, an the curl request below works on the command line:

```
curl 'https://subdomain.test.domain.com/api/v1/users/4508184' 
-X PUT 
-F 'user[avatar][url]= http://domain.com/canvas/avatar.jpg' 
-H "Authorization: Bearer tokenxxxxxxxxyyyyyyy"
```

Here I have translated the code above to PHP, but although the request is being sent it is not working because it says the "token is invalid".
I am 100% sure the token is working and is correct so I presume that there is something in my code

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => "{$baseUrl}{$userId}", 
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'PUT',  // -X
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => 'user[avatar][url]=http://domain/canvas/avatar.jpg', // -F
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header // -H
));
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Thank you

Comment: What does your $header looks like?

Comment: my $header looks like this: $header = "'Authorization: Bearer tokenxxxxxyyyyy'";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out. Change this code:

```
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header // -H
```

to this:

```
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array($header) // -H
```

curlopt_httpheader expect and array.

Answer (score 0):

Saw something in your $header (single quotes) does this work:

```
$header = "Authorization: Bearer tokenxxxxxyyyyy"; 
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "{$baseUrl}{$userId}", 
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'PUT',  // -X
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => 'user[avatar][url]=http://domain/canvas/avatar.jpg', // -F
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header // -H
));
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: I figure it out. Change this code:

CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header // -H

to this:

CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array($header) // -H

curlopt_httpheader expect and array.